# DOTENV not reading variables properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, pg-promise, dotenv

This is my file:

```
postgresU="myuser"
postgresP="mypass"
postgresH="myhost"
postgresDB="mydb"
postgresC="postgres://${postgresU}:{$postgresP}@{$postgresH}:5432/${postgresDB}"
```

In my nodejs app,

```
require('dotenv').config();
var connectionString = process.env.postgresC;
console.log("Connection String:",connectionString);
```

This prints:

```
Connection String: "postgres://${postgresU}:${postgresP}@${postgresH}:5432/${postgresDB}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a package like [dotenv-expand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand)  if you want to expand variables in .evn files.

Once installed (with npm or yarn) you can simply use a .env file with:

```
postgresU="myuser"
postgresP="mypass"
postgresH="myhost"
postgresDB="mydb"
postgresC="postgres://${postgresU}:${postgresP}@${postgresH}:5432/${postgresDB}"
```

and then process it with:

```
const dotenv= require('dotenv')
const dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand')
let myEnv = dotenv.config()
dotenvExpand(myEnv)

let connectionString = process.env.postgresC;
console.log(connectionString)
```

> postgres://myuser:mypass@myhost:5432/mydb